# how to convert plain array into nested object which is nested into parent object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to convert an plain array into object with additional parameter

Lets say, I have an object

```
var obj = [{
    index: 1,
    question: "If a carrier wave of 1000 kHz is used to carry the signal, the length of transmitting antenna will be equal to _____ ?",
    choices_list: ["300 m", "30 m", "3 m", "0.3 m"],
    answer: "300 m",
    explanation: "h =  c/v = 3 × 10^8/10^6 = 300 m",
},{...}
{...}
{...}
...
...]
```

now With the help of below code I'll convert `choices_list` in to object

```
res_quiz_data.forEach(key => {
    console.log(key.choices_list);

    const map1 = key.choices_list.map(x => {
        return { selected: false, choice: x }
    });
    console.log(map1);
})
```

Output

```
JS: [300 m, 30 m, 3 m, 0.3 m]
JS: [{
JS:   "selected": false,
JS:   "choice": "300 m"
JS: }, {
JS:   "selected": false,
JS:   "choice": "30 m"
JS: }, {
JS:   "selected": false,
JS:   "choice": "3 m"
JS: }, {
JS:   "selected": false,
JS:   "choice": "0.3 m"
JS: }]
```

now i need to way to modify the main Json object

**Expected Output**

```
var obj = [{
    index: 1,
    question: "If a carrier wave of 1000 kHz is used to carry the signal, the length of transmitting antenna will be equal to _____ ?",
    choices_list: [{
       "selected": false,
       "choice": "300 m"
     }, {
       "selected": false,
       "choice": "30 m"
     }, {
       "selected": false,
       "choice": "3 m"
     }, {
       "selected": false,
       "choice": "0.3 m"
     }],
    answer: "300 m",
    explanation: "h =  c/v = 3 × 10^8/10^6 = 300 m",
    },
{....},
{....},
{....},
....
....]
```

Comment: So what is difficulties? Just assign result to obj.choices_list nstead of map1

Comment: @vikatakavi updated both ways, updating on the existing object and without mutating the existing object. Check below

Comment: you are just iterating through choices but not setting the values back to object.
change `const map1 = key.choices_list.map(x => {` to `key.choices_list = key.choices_list.map(x => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update as follows

```js
var obj = [{
    index: 1,
    question: "If a carrier wave of 1000 kHz is used to carry the signal, the length of transmitting antenna will be equal to _____ ?",
    choices_list: ["300 m", "30 m", "3 m", "0.3 m"],
    answer: "300 m",
    explanation: "h =  c/v = 3 × 10^8/10^6 = 300 m",
}]

var output = obj.map(o => {
  o.choices_list = o.choices_list.map(choice => ({selected: false,
  choice}))
  return o
})


console.log(output)
```

If you want to update on the same object, you can do as follows

```js
var _obj = [{
    index: 1,
    question: "If a carrier wave of 1000 kHz is used to carry the signal, the length of transmitting antenna will be equal to _____ ?",
    choices_list: ["300 m", "30 m", "3 m", "0.3 m"],
    answer: "300 m",
    explanation: "h =  c/v = 3 × 10^8/10^6 = 300 m",
}]

_obj.forEach(o => {
  o.choices_list = o.choices_list.map(choice => ({selected: false,
  choice}))
  return o
})


console.log(_obj)
```

Comment: unfortunately This is the perfect answer which saved my precious time. Thank you

Comment: happy to help kindly accept it if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option to make the logic simpler, you can [destructure object](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to operate separately on `choices_list` and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to build up the result without caring about the unchanged fields.

```js
const myArray = [{
  index: 1,
  question: "If a carrier wave of 1000 kHz is used to carry the signal, the length of transmitting antenna will be equal to _____ ?",
  choices_list: ["300 m", "30 m", "3 m", "0.3 m"],
  answer: "300 m",
  explanation: "h =  c/v = 3 × 10^8/10^6 = 300 m"
}, {
  index: 2,
  question: "Dummy question",
  choices_list: ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  answer: "d",
  explanation: "none"
}]

const res = myArray.map(({choices_list, ...a}) => ({
  ...a,
  choices_list: choices_list.map(x => ({selected: false, choice: x}))
}))

console.log(res)
```

Note that th solution does not mutate the original array, which is generally desirable.

Comment: May be syntax is different, but the above answer and your is giving same style of output. i don't even see timing difference in both the answer for 100 arrays.

Comment: No surprise the style of the outputs are the same because they are just slightly different means of reaching the same target. So, you can take this solution as a kind of syntactical sugar with ES6 facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't

```
obj.forEach((entry) {
    res_quiz_data.forEach(key => {
        console.log(key.choices_list);

        const map = key.choices_list.map(x => {
            return { selected: false, choice: x }
        });
        console.log(map);
    });
    entry.choices_list = map;
});
```

Good enough?

Comment: Man i have 100 's of array of objects, how obj.choices_list works. each time it loops and i need to assign it to correspnding element only .

Comment: @vikatakavi then just putting everything into a loop should work.

Comment: you mean `key.choices_list = map1;`?

Comment: @AZ_edited my answer with something similar to what I mean. Just need to change the res_quiz_data array for each iteration I guess. Like having another array to loop through.